# Xcode6 Swift add Launchscreen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

How can I add a launch screen after the app is finished?

I already have add a file "LaunchScreen.xib" but the app launches from the View Controller?

thx for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. Under Target > General > App Icons and Launch Images select the correct Launch Screen File and it works on every Iphone (4s, 5, 5s, 6, 6plus)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem before. This is my solution, hope it can help you:

1. Targets->general->App icons and launch images->launch image source add a `LaunchImage`
2. Click into `Images.xcassets` file, you add two png to `LaunchImage` 2x (640x960,iPhone4，4s), Retina 4 (640x1136，iPhone5，5s)
3. Add a png (640x1136) to `Images.xcassets`, it's name must be **Default-568h@2x**
4. Run the app

When you launch iPhone4~iPhone5s simulators, `LaunchScreen` is launched from 
`LaunchImage`, when you launch from iPhone6+, `LaunchScreen` is launched from `LaunchScreen.xib`.

Comment: i have no enough reputation to upload image［sad］